# [Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: this.$refs.canvas is undefined"

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

Im using Vue Chart in one of my project but getting this error.

Here is Chart Component

```
<line-example></line-example>
```

And this is my Script

```
<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/navbar/Navbar'
import {Line} from 'vue-chartjs'


export default {
    extends: Line,
    components:{
      Navbar,
      'line-example': Line
    },
    data(){
      return{
          dialog:null
      }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.renderChart({
          labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
          datasets: [
            {
              label: 'Data One',
              backgroundColor: '#FC2525',
              data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
            },{
              label: 'Data Two',
              backgroundColor: '#05CBE1',
              data: [60, 55, 32, 10, 2, 12, 53]
            }
          ]
        }, {responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false})

    }
  }
</script>
```

You can find the complete code here
https://github.com/Shakilzaman87/pukucrm/blob/master/src/components/dashboard/Dashboard.vue

Can anyone give me any idea about why this error happen ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok Im editing my question

Comment: if exists template tag, please remove..

Comment: please test if has incompatibility in your 'Navbar', comment the code

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a Single file template then you have to remove the 
 tag because you are extending a vue Element